# What is Arctic Control Area (ACA)?

Tags: terminology, airspace

I saw that in *Jeppesen airway manual* but I didn't find a definition for it. What is that?

How to establish it? Who establishes it and for what reason?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

from 
http://code7700.com/high_latitude.htm

Apparently defined by Transport Canada:

https://www.tc.gc.ca/media/documents/ca-publications/AIM-2018-1-E-ACCESS.pdf

page 192

Comment: Pondlife, how are you able to make the .png show up like that?

Comment: click 'edit' and study the changes.

Comment: @PeterKämpf to be precise they should click "edited X hours ago"

Comment: @Federico: That is even better, agreed. I learned MathML by clicking 'edit' on posts where I wondered "how the heck did they do this?"